# Why is my nsuserdefaults text not showing up instantly?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I push a button that saves an nuserdefaults text then the button takes me to the next view controller (View Controller 2).Then the UILabel in second controller reads the text. However, I always have to push the button twice to get the UILabel in View Controller 2 to read the nsuserdefault text. This is weird because my navigation title bar in second view controller can read nsuserdefaults instantly without pushing the button more than twice.

Viewcontroller 1

```
  NSString *calories = @"Test:1, 2, 3";
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
  setObject:calories forKey:@"Text"];
```

View Controller 2

```
 clabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,30, 320, 30)];
 clabel.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Text"];
 clabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
 clabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 12.0];
 clabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
 clabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
 [self.view addSubview:clabel];
```

Comment: [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchoronize]

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] after setting object ?

Comment: Just as a side notice - using `NSUserDefaults` to transfer data between different viewControllers is well, not quite right. `NSUserDefaults` are made primarily to store user settings or other sensitive data, but definitely not for transferring it to another VC -  there are much better ways to do it.

Comment: The UserDefaults is not supposed to be some sort of convenient singleton for passing data around your View Controllers.

Comment: The thing is that I may need to use the data to send information to an Email or something of that sort. My situation is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my problem why this was working for my navigation bar ,but not my uilabel.You have to add nsuserdefaults before the code that switches view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the user defaults to write them to storage, etc:

```
NSString *calories = @"Test:1, 2, 3";
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:calories forKey:@"Text"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

**Edit: Not actually required**

Comment: I see this advice repeated so often and it is plain wrong. You do _not_ need to synchronise user defaults every time you write a value.

Comment: Yes, you are actually right. Might be good though since nothing will be saved if the app will make an unclean exit. I would say if it is still a good idea to synchronise soon after changing the defaults.

Comment: And what's the problem with `synchronise`? The dogma of modern iOS development sounds like - _Always be prepared to stop_. And that's how it should be, actually.

Comment: @SergiusGee the problem is synchronise being offered as a solution to any and all problems involving user defaults when the actual issue always lies elsewhere - just like in this case (see the questioner's own answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
  setValue:calories forKey:@"Text"];
```

Then

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]ValueforKey:@"Text"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You are forgot below line of code. Once you put the data in userdefaults then you need to write synchronize.

```
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: Downvoting, for the same reason as jensolsson's answer above.